# Unwanted suffix in URL Symfony 6.3

Tags: symfony

I did experiment with annotations.yaml in routes folder. After that I have deleted the file. But now alle routes are now having automaticaly suffix :1 at the end and the application is not working. I have deleted manualy all in /var/cashe folder but the problem persists. What could couse such a problem?

[image]

Comment: If you run command `php bin/console debug:route` what is the result ?

Comment: Hi Skuti, when I run the command I get this:

In BaseNode.php line 52:
                                   
  The name must not contain "..".

Comment: Ok so could you please check if in one of your config files there is an extra dot somewhere or if there is a folder with an extra dot like ..git that is in fact .git (this is just an example)

Comment: Thanks for reply Skuti.

 I did solve the problem by using the version control for my files and reinstaling the libraries. I believe the problem was that I deleted annotations.yaml manualy. Because of that but some external library still remained in application and messed up the url's.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple files `config/routes.yaml`, `config/routes/*`
check all for a unwanted `prefix` attrib.

Comment: I did check those files nothing was changed in them. I am using Git, and these files were unchaged.